# Bring Application from background to front

Tags: android, eclipse, popup

I am trying to make a simple project that could move the application to background by using

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
        moveTaskToBack(true);
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

and now I am trying to bring the application to the front, displaying on the screen automatically even though user didn't reopen the application

For example, I set the timeout as 30 seconds, then I close the application (which is moved to background actually), after 30 seconds, the application will automatically move to front and shows text "Time Out". If I am playing games during time out, the game will pause and display the Time Out page, I tried to search for the solutions but the result is quite disappointing. the below are the codes I using now to bring the page to front, but it is only display in the app, unless user reopen the app then onli they can see the Time Out page otherwise they will not know

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.lolcash.lol.PopOut");
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
        startActivity(intent);
```

is there any other way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create a [service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html), this will run in background. When you want to bring the activity to front you can start it from the `Service`. 
Another solution would be to display a [notification](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html) with a message, when the user will tap it you can take him to the app.

Comment: Let me try first :)
will ask you more if any problem~
thanks ya

Comment: I tried to put this line in my BroadcastReceiver {context.startService(this,PopOut.class);}
but it shows that
The method startService(Intent) in the type Context is not applicable for the arguments (TextMessageReceiver, Class<PopOut>)
what is the problem?

Comment: you are sending 2 parameters to the method `startService`, it only accepts one, the intent. You should first create the intent and after that send it to the `startService` method

Comment: thank you~ now I can start the service ald.. is it correct if i call onStartCommand? because the app didnt show up at front but the Logcat get the service had started